# What to do after I signed a blank sheet of paper given to me by my manager?

Tags: human-resources, unprofessional-behavior

I work as a teacher in a kindergarten for almost two years now.

Last week, my manager called me to sign a warning letter about a small issue that is not my fault and not part of my job description. I refused to sign and my manager told me to discuss this the next day. The next day, I met my manager and after some discussion she told me "do not worry it is not a big deal, just sign this paper and I will write the warning paragraph later".

I have signed a completely white paper - not even a warning form; it is a completely blank piece of paper! Yes, this is the most idiotic and stupid act that anyone could do. I have now realised how dangerous what I did is. I don't know what I should do now?

My manager is not an ethical person; she has a high desire to feel important. She always wants to feel that all teachers are following her orders. I do not know what she is planning to do with this or if she is really planning to do something bad with it.

Shall I speak to HR about this case although I do not have any evidence?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88203/discussion-on-question-by-suzan-what-to-do-after-i-signed-a-blank-sheet-of-paper).

Comment: After this is over, please tell us what happened.

Comment: If its a good idea, somebody who knows more details about such things can feel free to turn it into an answer.

Comment: What country are you in? Laws differ.

Comment: What happened? Could we get an update?

Answer (score 272):

Yes you are in danger.

However, anything your manager does (like printing a new letter over the signature) is fraud, and quite the bad variety too.

As she was doing what she was doing in the capacity of your manager, this is now the problem of your school/company/district or whatever the organisation is where you work.

HR is not your friend but in this case they will (or at least should) be your ally. To be a bit safer you could make it sound like you are just asking a question ("(describe in detail what happened), hey what was this about?", that way you get both documentation and can stay on polite footing with HR. I'd recommend dropping by the office after the email too (if that is not too weird for a teacher in your district/area) just to chat up.

Do this *now*, get this on paper, leave the kids to twiddle their thumbs if you must.

Ok, maybe not leave the kids (as per comment) but I'd suggest getting at least a short "hey I have a question I'm very worried about, I'll email once I have time, mind if I drop by in the afternoon?" out of the way. Sociopaths have a tendency to proactively discredit their victims so you need to be ahead of that.

Comment: +1 - Not so sure about leaving the kids but hey :)

Comment: I'd leave the kids, to some one else... I'm sure you can find someone to watch them for 30 mins while you get this sorted.

Comment: This is a good answer, but in addition you really have to get something in writing from HR that confirms the communication. HR sometimes has the tendency to give you a sympathetic ear and then immediately swipe it all under the rug

Comment: @Twyxz It was *very* clearly a joke...

Comment: Perhaps the teacher's union would be a good ally as well.

Comment: Add to this; you should make sure that HR understands that no document which is not signed with at least one witness present should be considered valid. Boss can just photocopy the document now.

Comment: Isn’t this situation no different than if the manager forged the signature by copying it from elsewhere? The manager likely has the teacher’s signature on another piece of paper anyway.

Comment: @only_pro Really? Wow

Comment: @Hilmar - Since the biggest concern is this blank document with a signature floating around, I'd guess that "sweeping it under the rug" would mean making sure that blank signed paper is destroyed or never sees the light of day. I'd take that, at this point.

Comment: +1 just for this gem: **”Sociopaths have a tendency to proactively discredit their victims so you need to be ahead of that.”**

Comment: @Twyxz Yes. Now you know!

Comment: @only_pro thank you for making such an obvious statement

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: nope. "Sweeping it under the rug", means that HR will mainly just ignore it and hope that it disappears on it's own.

Comment: @Hilmar - So, more of pretending it didn't happen.... gotcha. The kind of active implication behind "sweeping" had me thinking you meant something a bit different. Thanks for clarifying for me.

Answer (score 210):

**Speak to HR immediately, you signed a blank piece of paper - make sure it stays blank**

Normally advice around speaking to HR is "HR are not your friend". However, this is in the context of bringing up general workplace greivances - as HR's remit is to protect the company, not the employees.

In this case, you have a manager who plans to break the law - by forging a document with your signature. This would put your kindergarten in a serious legal problem, especially if that forged document was ever used to terminate your employment. **This is exactly the kind of situation HR do not want to happen**.

You need to explain to them exactly what has happened (in writing via email, and then in person), and that there is now a blank sheet of paper with your signature, you believe will be used to fraudulently create a signed warning letter.

Importantly, I'd recommend you only focus on the potential misuse of your signature on the blank letter. Anything else, such as personal issues with this manager - will not necessarily be in their interest to help you with (and the usual "HR doesn't love you" advice applies).

---

*For your personal sake; it's worth adding that while it was an extremely stupid move to sign that paper - it is understandable, and abusive managers have managed to push each of us to lower our personal standards at one time or another (so don't worry about how it happened, just get it sorted). Legally, that paper has no value, and you need to remember that you haven't legally given somebody the right to write whatever they want - you have unfortunately just given them the opportunity to break the law.*

Comment: To OP: read this last paragraph again. And once more. This is abusive behaviour, and it is not your fault. We all wish you can do better next time, but it's completely understandable that you fell into this. Now go fix it :)

Answer (score 70):

Amplifying what the other answers already said: Talking to HR is NOT enough, you MUST file a **written report**.

Write exactly down what happened with as much detail (time, location, names, quotes) as you can recall. Stick to the facts, don't put any emotion or interpretation into it. Take this report to HR make a copy for yourself. Make HR sign your copy and confirm in writing that they have received the report. Insist that they attach this report to your personell file.

You may want to have this looked over by a lawyer, before you file it.

Make sure you are friendly and co-operative with HR, but also be assertive when they try to push you off or ignore you. I don't think they can legally refuse to accept the report and confirm it's reception (again, a lawyer would help here).

Unfortunately, your blank signature could be a ticking time bomb. HR may try to sweep it under the rug and then it pops up 1 year later as a signed confession to something nasty. At that time, there may be entirely different people in HR. This needs to be documented clearly and you need written proof of it, so you have something to defend yourself with if you need it.

Ideally you get the paper back, but this may not happen. It's possible that your manager will simply deny that this happened. Or she may say "I already threw it away" or "I can't find it at the moment". HR won't be able to do much about this. Hence, you need thorough protection in writing.

Comment: I don't think you can "make" HR sign anything, but typing, "I acknowledge receipt of this document" with a space for s signature could make it more palatable.

Answer (score 48):

Okay, in matters like this.

## HR is your new best friend.

This manager is dangerous, and likely committing some fraudulent action.  I won't scold you about signing a blank anything as you already realize the implications.

Write down all the events leading up to this, detail the event itself, walk into HR with your account and ask to see any additions to your file since that date.

The danger is not just to you, but to anyone else that deals with this person.  HR needs to be alerted to protect you and any other employees who engage with him/her.  This is one of the reasons HR exists, and this is absolutely a matter for them.

*Run*, don't walk to the HR department.

Comment: Don't you usually say "HR is not your friend"? It seems this is a big deal.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 HR is your "friend" not when you're unhappy about your work for some generic reason, but in cases where yours and the company's interests align. In this case, stopping a widely publicised lawsuit where the manager in a school commits fraud most certainly causes those interests to align.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 HR is _still_ not being your friend. It just so happens that what's bad for the company/entity is _also_ bad for HR, so HR, in _this particular case_, will work to correct that, which just so happens to also be what you need. The differences are subtle.

Comment: *"The enemy of your enemy is your friend."*  In this case, HR is your friend.  This manager is as much a threat to HR as it is to the OP.

Comment: LOL great answer and headline  :)  :)

Comment: @Nelson It's always good to keep in mind [Maxim 29](http://schlockmercenary.wikia.com/wiki/The_Seventy_Maxims_of_Maximally_Effective_Mercenaries).

Comment: Not just new additions since that date -- that blank piece of paper with your signature could easily be used to create a back-dated document.  Ask to get an entire copy of your personnel file created and documented, so that you have some protection against back-dated documents being added later. (Yes, this happened to someone I know. Her HR file was clean on Monday and on Wednesday contained a paper trail of months of formal notifications that served as justification for why she was fired.)

Answer (score 17):

#### Report this to the police

> "do not worry it is not a big deal, just sign this paper and I will
>   write the warning paragraph later".

Your boss has literally stated outright that she intends to forge a document. This is a serious crime in all jurisdictions and nations that I am aware of. Moreover, the implications could be anything from severe to devastating to you personally (and the company too).

I like the other answers, but I would most certainly **report this to the police as well**. Your boss has admitted to planning something criminal.

The police will almost certainly have to write a report on what you tell them. Although I do recommend documenting this with HR as well,  HR may or may not do their job, and the police is much more reliable to document this properly for you. If worst comes to worst (which, indeed, it very well may), and your job ends up on the line, having this documented by the police can be very useful. You may end up in court, and having this documented by the police may be a big help.

In the best case scenario, the police gets a search warrant, goes to the office of the boss, and finds the blank piece of paper, backing up your story. (I realise this may be an unlikely outcome, but your story is the type which triggers the "justice" part in the conscience of people, and therefore it is not impossible.

I realise that reporting your boss to the police is a rather aggressive approach, but this is also a quite extreme situation. Your boss has already admitted an intent to commit fraud against you, and the company. She has already taken the gloves off. You have very little to lose here. Your boss deserves to lose her job over this, not you.

#### Go to your/a union

Also, if you are not a member of a **union**, join one now, and ask them for assistance. They typically have legal teams which can help in such situations.

#### Consult a lawyer

If somehow a union can not provide a lawyer for you, consider consulting one on your own, if you can afford it.

#### Try to get the paper back, or to get evidence of what happened

This last part has only a mediocre chance of success, but you might as well try. There is a downvoted (possibly for typesetting, not content) answer which suggests talking to the boss about it, while secretly recording it, hoping that she somehow admits to what she has done, given that you are located in one of the few jurisdictions in which that is legal. If you are sure that you happen to find yourself in one of those jurisdictions, then I find that idea reasonable. If she does admit that and you get it recorded, that would be a rather valuable defense to you, and it would no longer be her words against yours. If you do happen to have such a conversation, you can, in the same conversation, ask for the paper back. This will put her on the spot, and it will be difficult for her to hold on to the paper without admitting that it exists. Also, there is the chance that she may give it back voluntarily. In that conversation, you may actually be polite. You can tell her that you thought about it, and you would like to see the warning before you sign it, and therefore want the blank paper back. If she refuses, you can step it up a notch, and inform her that what she is doing is illegal. After all that, I would say you have a pretty good chance of either getting the paper back, **or** getting a recording of her admitting what happened. In the worst case scenario that she just pretends she has no idea what you are talking about, and does not give you anything, then you have not really lost much, and you can proceed with HR, the police, a/your union, and a lawyer.

If recording without knowledge is not legal in your jurisdiction, I do not see why you should not have the conversation anyway, without recording. After all, what she is doing is pretty insane, and there may be a chance she has an ounce of sense in her and decides to give it back, fearing the possible consequences of committing fraud.

#### Act NOW, do not wait

Time may be of the essence here. Having this documented and dated **before** the manager shows her forgery to anyone else and has **that** recorded, may be quite important for getting people to believe you here. Also, by acting quickly you can make something happen before she even writes anything on the sheet in the first place. The sheet of paper with nothing but your signature on it is the single most damning evidence here if found in the possession of your boss. Note that regardless of what the manager writes on that paper, it will be a forgery, and criminal. I would not waste even a second here, I would immediately get this documented.

Comment: +1 for reporting to the police.

Comment: `The police will almost certainly have to write a report on what you tell them.` Not necessarily. While you can file reports about anything, remember that someone has to take it seriously first. The police are busy enough that they are likely to ignore this and dismiss you out of hand (no actual fraud has happened yet and laws vary on this by jurisdiction). You can always demand to file a report, but now you're getting on their bad side. It's unlikely this goes beyond the report itself. A lawyer or union rep is a better suggestion.

Comment: @Machavity Yeah, I agree with that. In some cases you may have to demand to file a report. I would still demand that, though, as you do not have much to lose. Obviously, that will likely mean that the police will not offer much more help, and one should indeed proceed with unions, a lawyer, etc.

Answer (score 15):

There are some notes about going to HR about "potential misconduct" which is part of why I'm taking the time to write this as a separate answer.

You can not control what your manager does. You can not anticipate what your manager will do. Speculating as to what your manager conceivably *might* do is a good way to give them an actionable grievance that you've yourself recorded with HR and turn this into a back and forth over something other than what actually happened, which is what you don't want in a situation like this.

### You do need to document this with HR

But to be clear, you need to document **only** what **you** did and why **you** did it:

Your manager requested you sign a blank sheet of paper. You signed a blank sheet of paper and gave it to your manager, per their request. [You can repeat what they told you about why they were making that request, but I would avoid getting embroiled in that: ideally keep this as cleanly focused on the basic hard facts as possible, so there's not room for argument later on about who said what.] You didn't think anything of it at the time, and you try to be a good employee who does what they are told [or whatever you'd like to say in that regard of following orders], but for clarification's sake you would now like documented that what you signed was a blank sheet of paper, and that is the only thing you are agreeing to having signed, because THAT is what you signed.

If a date or something else was requested on it, note that. If it is literally just your signature, note that.

Don't speculate on what your manager might or might not do with the blank paper you signed. Don't accuse your manager of intending to commit fraud. (if your manager DOES commit fraud, then address it as such: but the key here is do NOT accuse them of something that they haven't actually done yet)

Do create a paper trail. Email it, BCC a personal account, and request to schedule a discussion or at least a "quick chat" *in person* with someone regarding making sure it gets properly documented. When you go, make sure you print off a paper copy to take with you so you have a reference of what you sent that you can refer back to if things get stressful, and as a reminder to keep it simply focused on the basic facts of what you did and that it was at the manager's request.

Don't make a big deal out of it: just be *calm yet firm* about wanting it documented. If HR (ideally) wants to make a big deal out of it, that's on HR, let them be the ones to press the concern and don't interject it yourself. Keep your own focus on what you did and why, and your expressed concerns related to that specifically, not on what your manager *might* or might not do. Don't be the one who turns it into a big thing, because other than being an odd and inappropriate request, nothing has happened yet. Don't accuse your manager of anything at this point. If necessary or pressed, you can state that your concern is something very mundane and not specifically related to your manager, like "what if it gets lost and someone else finds it?" but my advice would be to simply keep things straightforward as a matter of just wanting it documented in your record since it was at your manager's request, but that you have no specific concerns and just want an official record of having done so per request.

If you do this and it turns into something where HR has you sit down across from your manager regarding this, don't try to engage. Don't be the one who asks the manager why they did that. Don't speculate. Just stick to the line that you just wanted what you did per request documented, and that all you did was sign a blank sheet of paper, which is all you agree to having signed, which hopefully everyone can agree is an odd thing to have signed (again, do not speculate about what someone else MIGHT do with such a piece of signed paper, focus only on what you did and that it was per a manager's request/order). Again, if pressed on why you are wanting it documented, stick to your immediate concern over it being strange to sign a blank piece of paper, not what might or might not be done with it.

Comment: The boss specifically said "just sign this paper and **I will write the warning paragraph later**" (emphasis mine). That right there is admitting that she intends to commit fraud by forgery. The OP can not prove to anyone that the boss said that, however, OP can also not prove that the boss made them sign the blank paper. (Only someone with the right to search the office of the boss can prove that.) Therefore, when recounting the story neutrally, I would include the quote from the boss in which she admitted her intentions.

Comment: @Revetahw I don't at all disagree, but that's effectively hearsay (no, this isn't about getting into what's going to hold up in court) and easily turns into who claimed what, who's telling the truth and who's not. Better to let the manager be the one who admits that to HR when HR asks why, if at all possible, than being the one who tells HR that that's what the manager said and then have it go sideways into "that's not what I said!"

I don't trust someone who does this to not try claiming that the person bringing this to HR is just lying. The less it relies on claims of what was said…

Comment: Yes, she can (and most likely will) deny that, but she can deny having made OP sign the blank sheet as well, so what is the difference?

Comment: @Revetahw The difference is focus and derailment. When dealing with someone who may be anticipated to lie about events (because they're already doing something very untrustworthy to put it mildly) it's best to keep the points of contention to a minimum. It also provides a point where HR can instead be the ones asking "why", and if she does answer truthfully it's from her own mouth. If the manager actually thinks that what she's doing is in some way ok, she's more likely to follow through with a truthful response on a "why" question if it's not already a point raised contentiously as an issue.

Comment: One key here, though, is that honestly the manager's "why" or excuse **doesn't actually matter**. The action itself is completely inappropriate, and that's what should be focused on. Providing whatever the manager *said* at the time of "why" is just one more detail to get derailed on and get lost on whether the purported "reason" might be valid, despite the action not being in any way.

Comment: That is a good point, the manager asking for a signed blank sheet in the first place is so beyond unacceptable that it is perhaps not needed to go into more detail that can distract from the central point.

Answer (score 12):

Don't trust HR alone to document it. They are not your friend, and woukd be happy for this to go away, e.g. By you going away.

### Comey that conversation

"To Comey" is a new verb that means to [write down](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/james-comey-document-meetings-trump_us_5938594ce4b00610547ed0cb) your recollection of events as soon as you can, because you feel there may later be disagreement over what happened.  This should be done *contemporaneously*, or ASAP after the event.   For instance, Comey sat in his car right after the meeting and wrote it down on a notepad.  This proved very useful later.

I advise doing more.  First, write down your recollection of the meeting.   Be truthful and create a recording of the facts that would be difficult to challenge.  Second, have it notarized, because you are not James Comey.  That proves it was contemporaneous, and you didn't modify your recollection to suit the later situation, which humans tend to do.

This goes in your pocket to be used later, if pushing comes to shoving.

Third, I would write a courtesy letter capturing in short form your recall of events. Something like this

> Thank you for speaking with me today about the Jan. 3 incident, and hearing my side of events.  As I said, I feel this and this and this, and you pointed out this and this and this.  I recall we found a middle ground of this and this and this.
>
> We also agreed that you would write a modified warning letter to that general effect.  For expediency, you asked me to sign a blank piece of paper on which that warning letter would be later placed, and I complied.  I would like to have a copy of that letter when complete.
>
> Again, thank you for taking the time to discuss the matter with me.  Usual salutation, signature.

Nothing threatening in there.  **But it lays out the facts as they happened**, and documents the existence of this blank signed letter, and puts him on notice that you intend to challenge any inappropriate use of it. Sneaky people hate facts being stated openly.   Decent people don't care.

Then, go have that verbal conversation with HR.

Answer (score 6):

The prevailing advice seems to be to talk to HR about it and document it there.
Note that a lot of these same people (on different questions) would probably tell you *to not go* to HR.

If the trip to HR does not go to your benefit, I think that you should write out what happened sign it, and get it notarized.  That is admissible in court if the words above your signature turn out to be something other than what you were told they would be - and maybe even if they were what you were told that they would be.

There may also be a police report that you can file - as the intent could be fraud and you felt that you were under duress and had to sign the report. I presume you're under duress or at least stress because you mention how bad an idea it was to do that.

Comment: You don't go to HR if you were having drinks after hours with a coworker and they made some racist comments (didn't happen on company time, they don't care); you don't go to HR because that guy in accounting has bad B.O. (it's not illegal to stink - sadly); You absolutely **do** go to HR when your boss makes you sign a blank piece of paper and promises to write out the contents later.  HR exists to protect the company, and this sort of thing could seriously damage the company if it wound up in court. That's the difference here.

Comment: @Steve-O Yes.  I was trying to convey: "many people who would normally tell you to not go to HR are telling you to go to HR.  In the event that the trip to HR doesn't go in a useful direction... here's another idea."

Comment: @Steve-O I think the point is that if even those of us who are known for saying "HR IS NOT YOUR FRIEND" are saying, "Go to HR", the OP should take it seriously.

Answer (score 5):

Speak to a LAWYER **immediately**!

Best, one for public service employment if the kindergarten is run by the government.

Follow their instructions.

I personally would ask the manager to hand you back the paper.

Ideally empty, but it might well be too late for that.

Make sure, she handed you the original and keep it, DON'T HAND IT BACK.

Don't let her threaten or coerce you, even at the risk of your job. (I doubt that would fly as a reason and if she trumps up any other reason you can point to the empty paper she made you sign and claim she retaliates)

If it's empty, it should be safe to destroy it (maybe best after some time passed,but ask a lawyer)

If what she wrote is bad for you in any way or you disagree, bring it to your lawyer (she may have copies).

*But lawyers may have a very different way to deal with this, so go to one as soon as possible.*

Comment: Maybe have your lawyer accompany you.

Answer (score 3):

Inform HR what has happened. HR MUST give you a signed document where they accept what you told them which you keep safe.

HR then knows that if a document with your signature turns up in the future, you can claim that you didn't sign it. Kind of a "get out of jail" card. So HR would be well advised to get that blank sheet from your manager, call you in, and destroy it in front of you with you signing that you saw it destroyed. That way everything is cleaned up.

You would need them as a witness anyway, because a document might turn up in the future that says you sold your car to the manager for $1,000.

Answer (score 1):

Although many answers warn of potential grave consequences, let's not forget that the malicious intention of the manager is not a given.

I would recommend to first of all go to the manager, and say you don't feel good about the blank signature, and ask for it back. There is a chance that he/she has no malicious intent, and will simply give it to you. You can always sign a sheet again once he/she has printed the proper text on it.

Of course, if he/she is *declining* to return it, you should go after the recommendations from the other answers.

Comment: If they were good intentions, there would be no need to a so underhanded move as a blank sheet

Comment: While asking for the paper back is not a bad idea (as long as you do other things as well), I disagree that there may be no malicious intention here. The manager has indeed **admitted** to you that she is about to create a forged document. That can be described in no other way than malicious.

Comment: @Revetahw: The manager agreed to write a document with a warning that the OP should sign and asked for his signature _first_ rather than having him sign it first. While _technically_ this is a forged document, many people give signed blank documents to fill to their secretaries, or even have them forge their signature. Or managers requesting monthly timesheets signed before end of month. A bad idea from a legal standpoint? Sure, but from a paperwork pov it's practical. So, the manager intentions do not need to be malicious to the OP, only silly.

Comment: @Ángel It is not something innocuous though, it is a written warning, one of the most negative things you can give an employee. This combined with the forgery aspect makes me call this certainly malicious. It **could** theoretically be that the manager is so stupid that she did this thinking it was perfectly normal, in which case, well, it is gross incompetence and almost as serious.

Comment: @Revetahw: Well, the fact that the manager is not an ethical person should be a big red flag. And given the context, I agree that _in this case_, it seems as if having a malicious intent.

Answer (score -3):

Calm down, you made a mistake. Unfortunately running in and requesting that paper you signed (which possibly does not even exist - according to her, when challenged) is an issue.

Several steps:

1. Remember and write down *everything* about that day. What you where wearing, what she was wearing, the time of day (before lunch, etc). Often times, seemingly irrelevant facts can help to corroborate your story, at the very least someone else may be able to verify these facts and lend weight to your story.
2. Go back and talk to her about it, noting your discomfort with the whole thing. [*You may be able to legally record the conversation depending on your state/country.*](https://www.mwl-law.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/LAWS-ON-RECORDING-CONVERSATIONS-CHART.pdf)

You may also try talking to a trusted coworker and ask if they know of anything like this happening to anyone else.

*If you do plan to record and you have the legal safety to do so, practice and rehearse this act, ideally with a friend or two to ensure you take a good recording and you don't seem overly suspicious doing it.*

**HR is not your friend** - they will, wherever possible, side with the manager - your acts will be construed as you getting second thoughts after signing the paper.

Comment: Uhm, there is bold text and stuff here so you don't have to SCREAM AT US USING CAPS. ;-)

Comment: What @DonQuiKong said ;)

Comment: **HR IS NOT YOUR FRIEND** is practically my catch phrase around here.  in this case, they are.

Comment: While there are many problems with this answer, I believe that if you are sure doing so is legal in your jurisdiction, then attempting to make this recording is not a bad idea at all.

Comment: HR may not be your friend, but in this case, HR's interests and your interests align.  HR doesn't want the company to be at the wrong end of a fraud accusation, and you don't want to need to accuse the company of fraud.

Comment: I can say unequivocally from my own  direct observation as an IT operative in many large companies ( greater than 2,000 employees) I have had access to Outlook and SQL Server ( Ceridian HR databases) and often had to pull data for legal - the pattern is always the same.

HR protects the company, and that means your manager(s) NOT YOU.

If you contact HR w/o corroboration and your manager denies it you are sunk

Answer (score -4):

Take notes and write down the chain of events as well as you remember as soon as possible and the time that they happened. I would wait and see what your manager writes in before you take any further action.

Comment: -1 - see [@Hilmar's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/126286/10905)  A year from now that signed paper could have something far worse than a resignation on it.  Passively hoping for the best is not a wise answer.

Comment: She just sold her house for one dollar. Why wait for the manager to show the contract to the bank before taking action?

Comment: The manager said they would show the write up to the OP and that it would be minor. If it’s minor then there is no problem. If it’s major then there is a problem. The OP doesn’t yet know if there is a problem and doesn’t know how to properly react yet. If it’s no problem and the OP overreacts, then there is a new problem. I’m not advocating doing nothing, I’m advocating understanding what the OP should be reacting to before they react. You don’t just shoot at any sound you hear in the back yard, you look and see if it’s dangerous. If you go off shooting, well you might have a new problem.

Comment: @Tombo Time may be of the essence here. Having this documented and dated **before** the manager shows her forgery to anyone else and has **that** recorded, may be quite important for getting people to believe you here. Note that regardless of what the manager writes on that paper, it will be a forgery, and criminal. I would not waste even a second here, I would immediately get this documented.

Comment: BTW you cannot sell a house with a single signature

Answer (score -6):

These are all "feel good" answers.  You don't have a chance.  Look for another job, immediately.  You can waste your time and effort trying to fight city hall if you wish.  Been there; done that:  Lawyers, court, and all.  It's useless.  They hold all the cards.  The realistic way to conserve as much of your time, effort, and frustration as possible is just to leave the job as soon as you possibly can.  Anyone who tells you different is just trying to candy-coat a losing situation.  You, and every well-meaning employee with a sadistic manager in the US, are toast.  There is nothing you can do now except avoid "chasing bad money with good."  Say goodbye to your kids.

Comment: I do not believe OP has specified country.

Comment: We don't even know what the manager is going to do with the blank piece of paper yet, so leaving your job over it may be a complete overreacting. If they use it to do something bad to the employee it may or may not be worth fighting at that point, but giving up after one understandable mistake is ridiculous